# format collection in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs

Hi i need to format my Collection in order to for my Rest to accept the request. ( I recreated my project so i already know specifically what format my REST accepts )

The format should be :

```
{"input":"{invoice:[{}]","InvoiceDetails:[{},{},{}]}}
```

So in my backbone project i have:

```
CartCollection //collection
InvoiceDetailsCollection //collection
Invoice //model
InvoiceDetail //model
Cart //model
```

This is my save function:

```
save: function(){
    invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice.set({POSWorkstationID: "POS7"});
    invoice.set({POSClerkID: "admin"});
    invoice.set({CustomerName: "Alice in Wonderland Tours"});
    invoice.set({IsFreightOverwrite: true});
    invoice.set({BillToCode: "CUST-000009"});
    InvoiceDetailCollection.add([{Invoices: invoice}]);

    _.each(this.collection.models, function(cart){
        InvoiceDetailCollection.add( [{InvoiceDetails: cart }]);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(InvoiceDetailCollection.toJSON()));
}
```

My Current Format is this

```
[{"Invoices":{"POSWorkstationID":"POS7","POSClerkID":"admin","CustomerName":"Alice in Wonderland Tours","IsFreightOverwrite":true,"BillToCode":"CUST-000009"}},{"InvoiceDetails":{"Qty":"1","ItemCode":"ITEM-000004","ItemDescription":"Old World Lamppost\r\n\r\n","RetailPrice":107.99,"SalesPrice":107.99}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in this setup looks *standard*.

The way you manage the `InvoiceDetailCollection` is not like a normal `Collection`, looks more like a `Model` with two `Collections` into. A Collection is fed with a `Model` or the Hash to build a Model not with this *key/value* pairs that doesn't match with the `Collection.model`.

Then the URL you want to build has a *magic* root key called `input` then one key `invoice` (lowcase) which contains an array of only one element which is a Hash, then `InvoiceDetails` (camelcase) which you are **continuously reseting** to the actual `cart` content.

I think what you need is:

- `InvoiceDetailsCollection`: keeping all the carts
- `Invoice`: the invoice
- `Input`: the model that keeps both `Invoice` and `InvoiceDetails`

Then:

1. Create the `Invoice` Model.
2. Feed the `InvoiceDetailsCollection` with your carts.
3. Add the Invoice to Input: `Input.set( "invoice", invoice )`
4. Add the InvoiceDetailsCollection to Input: `Input.set( "invoice_details", InvoiceDetailsCollection )`

Overwrite the `Input.toJSON` to returns `input: this.toJSON()` *(code simplified)*.

But still I think your live could be easier if you could change this URL for something more REST. I think that all this info belongs to the `Invoice` Model so you could accept a request like:

- POST: `/invoices`
- DATA: `{ "POSWorkstationID": "POS7", "POSClerkID": "admin", ... , "Details": [{}, {}] }`

This way you can remove the `Input` Model that I suggested to wrapper all the weird behavior and keep the `InvoiceDetailsCollection` into the `Invoice` Model.

Comment: InvoiceDetailsCollection: keeping all the carts // Actually i'm doing that. Just that i added InvoiceDetails while adding the carts to InvoiceDetailCollection.